# Background replacement with 3D moving objects using Intel RealSense SDK

Tags: c#

I have done background replacement with static image and video using RealSense and c#, but now the requirement is to replace the background with the 3D moving object in still background.

Is it possible with RealSense?

Comment: It's not really clear what you're asking here. What is "replac[ing] the background with 3D moving object in still background"? Can you give examples?